# Marking overlapping paths with off-color borders

Tags: adobe, adobe-illustrator

Say I have an image of a rose which I want to trace:
[image]

I construct a few curvature shapes with it's stroke weight set to 5 like so:
[image]

Say I'd now like to see which stroke is placed over another, is there any way for me to do so?

Say my bottom layered stroke crosses a top layered stroke, it then might draw two little lines across the stroke like so:

[image]

Is there any way to set up such functionality? Or mimic it? It would help work like this a ton.

The program could get the order of overlap right by looking at the layer orders, which you would of course have to manually order yourself. But having a feature that enables me to see which shape is on top of which when they're overlapping would be great.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming or scripting. You'd probably be better off asking this on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Whoops you're right. I thought I posted on there, as I had it open in a different tab and it still let me post under the tag adobe-illustrator